# Hiveserver2 Java API

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, thrift, hortonworks-data-platform

I've been able to connect to a hiveserver (1) created with

```
hive --service hiveserver -v -p 10001
```

using the following java:

```
TSocket transport = new TSocket("hive.example.com", 10001);     
transport.setTimeout(999999999);
TBinaryProtocol protocol = new TBinaryProtocol(transport);
Client client = new ThriftHive.Client(protocol); 

transport.open();        
client.execute("SHOW TABLES");     
System.out.println(client.fetchOne());
transport.close();
```

Does an equivalent exist for hiveserver2, and if so what is it? The best I have found is a [design proposal](https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/hiveserver2-thrift-api.html) and I have yet to find any documentation. It looks like Cloudera has something set up for python [here](https://github.com/cloudera/hue/blob/master/apps/beeswax/src/beeswax/server/hive_server2_lib.py)

Alternatively, what is the best way to run arbitrary Hive queries from Java? If it is relevant, I'm running on Hortonworks Data Platform 1.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered using the [HiveClient JDBC interface?](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveClient)

Comment: It was considered and rejected by someone else on my team before we started on the thrift approach. I will find out why and if it made direct use of hiveserver2 necessary or just more appealing (assuming it works).

Comment: We are actually trying to launch this from ColdFusion and have so far been unable to use Hive ODBC as a ColdFusion data source. Since the thrift approach requires calling off to Java anyway, we are going to try calling off to Java then use the JDBC instead of thrift directly. I haven't given up on thrift yet, but hopefully the JDBC will just work.

Answer (score 4):

The server process is expecting a SASL handshake from the client (which is why you can see TSaslServerTransport in the stack trace). Use TSaslClientTransport as a wrapper for your TSocket connection - you'll also need to pass an appropriate configured SaslClient instance to the constructor as well. Alternatively, you can modify the hive-site.xml to turn SASL authentication off.

```
<property><name>hive.server2.authentication</name><value>NOSASL</value></property>
```

Comment: Thanks, karieanis. To all future readers of this question, karieanis may have the missing piece which makes my answer work. The reason seedhead is accepted instead of karieanis is that I have verified seehead's answer "works", but I have not been able to verify karieanis's. If anyone gives this a try an is successful let me know and I'll mark karieanis as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of searching I managed to generate a Java thrift server and client for hiveserver 2 using cli_service.thrift found in Hortonworks Data Platform 1.2. If anyone is interested, you can find it in [this tarball](http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP-1.2.0/repos/centos6/tars/hive-0.10.0.21.tar.gz). Once I did that and imported the resulting files my IDE let me know that the Hiveserver2 client API was in the jars I had all along. Unfortunately though, I was not able to find it in the Apache hive jars so in Maven, adding this to you pom.xml doesn't quite cut it.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
  <artifactId>hive-service</artifactId>
  <version>0.10.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I added the 0.10.0.21 version of hive-server for the HDP 1.2 release to my repository and referenced that instead. Then I manually added all of it's dependencies to my pom.xml, including several other 0.10.0.21 hive jars from HDP. Since this process is somewhat tangential to my answer, I won't go into more detail about this unless someone asks for it.

Actually getting the API to work is another thing entirely. Through a combination of poking around the dozens of files generated by thrift, looking at cli_service.thrift, and looking at the [Apache JDBC implementation](https://github.com/apache/hive/tree/trunk/jdbc/src/java/org/apache/hive/jdbc) (which is the only example I know of for writing against the Hiveserver2 thrift API), I came up with the following code which is almost a direct translation of the Hiveserver (1) example:

```
TSocket transport = new TSocket("hive.example.com", 10002);

transport.setTimeout(999999999);
TBinaryProtocol protocol = new TBinaryProtocol(transport);
TCLIService.Client client = new TCLIService.Client(protocol);  

transport.open();
TOpenSessionReq openReq = new TOpenSessionReq();
TOpenSessionResp openResp = client.OpenSession(openReq);
TSessionHandle sessHandle = openResp.getSessionHandle();

TExecuteStatementReq execReq = new TExecuteStatementReq(sessHandle, "SHOW TABLES");
TExecuteStatementResp execResp = client.ExecuteStatement(execReq);
TOperationHandle stmtHandle = execResp.getOperationHandle();

TFetchResultsReq fetchReq = new TFetchResultsReq(stmtHandle, TFetchOrientation.FETCH_FIRST, 1);
TFetchResultsResp resultsResp = client.FetchResults(fetchReq);

TRowSet resultsSet = resultsResp.getResults();
List<TRow> resultRows = resultsSet.getRows();
for(TRow resultRow : resultRows){
    resultRow.toString();
}

TCloseOperationReq closeReq = new TCloseOperationReq();
closeReq.setOperationHandle(stmtHandle);
client.CloseOperation(closeReq);
TCloseSessionReq closeConnectionReq = new TCloseSessionReq(sessHandle);
client.CloseSession(closeConnectionReq);

transport.close();
```

This was run against a Hiveserver2 server launched with:

```
export HIVE_SERVER2_THRIFT_PORT=10002;hive --service hiveserver2
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting the same behavior as when I tried to run a Hiveserver (1) client against Hiveserver2. `transport.open()` works, but the first request (in hiverserver2's case `client.OpenSession()` as opposed to hiveserver's (1) `client.execute()`) hangs. Wireshark shows that the TCP segment is ACK'd. There is no console output or anything written to the logs until I kill my client or the request times out, then I get:

```
13/03/14 11:15:33 ERROR server.TThreadPoolServer: Error occurred during processing of message.
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport$Factory.getTransport(TSaslServerTransport.java:219)
    at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:189)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:129)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:84)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.receiveSaslMessage(TSaslTransport.java:182)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport.handleSaslStartMessage(TSaslServerTransport.java:125)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.open(TSaslTransport.java:253)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport.open(TSaslServerTransport.java:41)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport$Factory.getTransport(TSaslServerTransport.java:216)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:256)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:317)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:127)
    ... 10 more
```

Someone seems to have run into a similar problem with a Python client. I lack the reputation to post a link, so if you want to see their (unresolved) question Google `hiveserver2 thrift client python grokbase`

Since it doesn't work, this is only a partial answer to my question. However, now that I have the API I will make a new question for getting it to work. I won't be able to link to that either, so if you want to see the follow up look in my user history.

Comment: I think your approach is very good. Have you found an answer?

Comment: I went with the Hive JDBC suggested by seedhead's answer because I was unable to find an answer. The answer by karieanis showed up after I had switched approaches. karieanis's answer sounds very promising (I gave it an upvote) but I'm committed to the JDBC now so I haven't dug up my old code to test it. If you or anyone else can verify that my answer + karieanis's answer gets this to work I'll accept karieanis's answer.