# Facing issue in Hiveserver2 service

Tags: hadoop, hive, datastax-enterprise

I am using hiveserver2 for connection but after running few jobs in hive i am getting below error in hive log.

```
2014-12-30 05:55:54,594 ERROR server.TThreadPoolServer (TThreadPoolServer.java:run(234)) - Error occurred during processing of message.
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport$Factory.getTransport(TSaslServerTransport.java:219)
        at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:209)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:132)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:84)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.receiveSaslMessage(TSaslTransport.java:182)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport.handleSaslStartMessage(TSaslServerTransport.java:125)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.open(TSaslTransport.java:253)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport.open(TSaslServerTransport.java:41)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport$Factory.getTransport(TSaslServerTransport.java:216)
```

And after this i am not able to connect to hiveserver2 and after restarting hiveserver2 service i am able to connect.

What is the root cause of this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Check if this is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15415904/requests-hang-when-using-hiveserver2-thrift-java-client